# connect to interBase/firebird Database with laravel

Tags: laravel-5, firebird, interbase

i use win 10 X64 and laravel 5.4 and wamp 3 so i enable php_pdo_firebird and php_interbase ext

i use this package :
[laravel firebird](https://github.com/jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird/)

when i execute my program have error :
[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkbMi.png)

Comment: you connection string seems wrong. But because you did not put here the text of the error - I can not copy it. Read http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq260/ - you did not specified the folder of your database file - it is random file anywhere on any disk. Would not do. Also, as error text suggests, there is no Firebird installed and running on the specified localhost server. So no one is listening on the TCP port your PHP tries to connect to. Or maybe antivirus/firewall blocks this connection.

Comment: Please post errors and relevant code **as text** inside the question. Don't use images for this. Also Firebird and Interbase are not the same (and haven't been for 17+ years), please be explicit whether you use Firebird or Interbase (or if you really use both). Also specify the Firebird (or Interbase) version you use.

Answer (score 0):

Some times you need to make sure if you're using the right version of the firebird package with the version of laravel that it's compatible with. You better check it out and update them.